# How do I resolve ambiguous type names in PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to instantiate a Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server in PowerShell 2 and later. I have SQL Server 2012 an 2014 installed. When I call the following I get an ambiguous type name error.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server]$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $serverInstance
```

The result is this error about ambiguity in type name because two versions of SMO are installed:

> New-Object : Type name 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' is
>   ambiguous, it could be  'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, **Version=12.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server, Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, 
>   **Version=11.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'.

I have tried add-type and other methods to load a specific assembly, but it the ambiguity remains.

A workaround *might* be to use get-item rather than new-object, though I have not tested my script completely with the change.

How do I resolve this ambiguous type names in PowerShell?

Comment: `New-Object  'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server, Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' $serverInstance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) often posts answers as comments (I will concede and remove this if they post an answer):

```
New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server, Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' $serverInstance
```